Failed to link the C library against JNA, Cannot open shared object file
I am having issues with installing Cassandra 4.0 and 4.1 on my rhel 8 server.
I've tried using java 11 openjdk and Corretto 11 openjdk.
When I start Cassandra I would receive:
Native LibraryLinux.java - Failed to link the C library against JNA.  \
  Native methods will not be available.

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/jna8760917299733827163.tmp: \
  /tmp/jna8760917299733827163.tmp: cannot open shared object: Operation not permitted

I've tried adding these commands separate and together in cassandra-env.sh file:
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djava.io.tmpdir=$CASSANDRA_HOME/tmp"  
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djna.tmpdir=$CASSANDRA_HOME/tmp" 

I even tried export JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djava.io.tmpdir=$CASSANDRA_HOME/tmp"
Once that is input the error changes to:
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Failed to create temporary file for /com/sun/jna/win32-x86/jnidispatch.dll library: \
   JNA temporary directory 'cassandra/tmp' does not exist

Once I create it and start Cassandra a new error shows as:
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Failed to create temporary file for /com/sun/jna/win32-x86/jnidispatch.dll library: \
  JNA temporary directory 'cassandra/tmp' is not writable

I tried to change permissions, but it would go back to the original error.
Does anyone have a solution for this?

There are few things about your question which struck me as being very odd.
First up, you mentioned that you're trying to install Cassandra on a RHEL server but the error you posted references a Windows DLL:
... Failed to create temporary file for /com/sun/jna/win32-x86/jnidispatch.dll library: ...

This indicates to me that you've tried to install something that's supposed to be for Windows instead of Linux so that's something you need to look into.
In any case for most instances, this UnsatisfiedLinkError:
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/jna8760917299733827163.tmp: \
  /tmp/jna8760917299733827163.tmp: cannot open shared object: Operation not permitted

is usually due to the /tmp filesystem being mounted with the noexec flag. JNA needs to execute binaries so the mapped directory must have execute permissions.
I noted that you tried to map the JNA tmpdir to $CASSANDRA_HOME/tmp but Cassandra does not have access to it. You need to make sure that Cassandra has FULL access to the tmpdir which includes read, write and execute permissions.
In any case, make sure you've installed software components built for Linux platform then try again. Cheers!

I couldn't copy and paste the error because it's on a private network, but the software is for linux as rpm files. There were no /tmp files so i had to create one. Some sites says it should be in "usr/share/cassandra" so I created the /tmp directory and modified permissions, but it would say instead of no access to /tmp, it cannot create /tmp/jna5676373637 etc. I tried to make the /tmp in lib/cassandra directoryto no avail.  What should I do? If I need to complete uninstall and redo, what commands or if I need to create a /tmp folder, what command to give Cassandra full access?

How are you trying to start Cassandra? It sounds like an improper installation of Java 11 or Corretto 11.
I would recommend reviewing these resources to verify Cassandra, Java, and Corretto were installed correctly:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/install/installation-jdk-linux-platforms.html
https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/stable/cassandra/getting_started/installing.html

I installed cassandra manually with rpm files. I would enter "dnf install  <cassandra.tools rpm file>. For Corretto 11 or java 11, I would "dnf install .
